# Return From Living/Working

Tags: meaning, usage, gerunds

Is it standard English to write:

1. "He returned from living in Europe."
2. "He returned from working overseas."

where "return from" is followed by an activity instead of a place?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that works.

***from*** can indicate a previous or prior state or location.

In your examples, it indicates that his state/condition, prior to returning, was *living in Europe* and *working overseas*.